# Create Parallel Workflow activities

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I have an existing workflow service that opens a SQL Server CE database file and updates a server database with the contents of the mobile database. The service is hosted in IIS/AppFabric and responds to requests from an ASP.NET website.

The workflow is started by a request from the website that contains the database file to process. At one point in the workflow in the *SynchUp* activity, a reasonably substantial chunk of data is updated to the server database and as a result a subsequent request from the website that is processed in the *Pick* activity is timing out.

[image: Synch workflow]

I would like to somehow process that large chunk of data in a separate workflow so that subsequent requests to my main workflow aren't blocked. Is it possible from within my current workflow to effectively fire and forget a new workflow and pass it the parameters it needs to complete the database update even if the calling workflow has completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you send a one way message to a workflow service that is a fire and forget message.